# Japanese Synonym list - solr

Tags: solr

Does anyone know were I can find a Japanese synonym list to use for my solr schema? I don't speak Japanese at all, so I am unable to produce one myself.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Japanese synonyms from here [NICT Japanese WordNet Synonyms Database ver.1.0](http://nlpwww.nict.go.jp/wn-ja/eng/downloads.html)  and then prepare them to Solr format programmatically.